# FFMPEG stream RTSP to RTMP (Youtube) add logo

Tags: video, ffmpeg, youtube, stream

To stream video from IP cam to Youtube I'm using code (through Ubunu):
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i anullsrc -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://user:psw@192.168.0.100:554 -tune zerolatency -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt + -c:v copy -c:a aac -strict experimental -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/ -nostdin -nostats /dev/null 2>&1 &

It is a bee project for school
I have two cameras and two streams:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ws-VcLXo-hI

Everything is ok, but... I would like to know:
 1. **How to add png logo** to this strem. I have tried -i /home/user/rvvg_logo_round.png -codec:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -filter_complex overlay and another methods but without a result.
 2. Sometimes there is some problem during night and video streaming stops. **How to automatically check process status and restart stream.**
I have tried to create sh file  as described in http://videos.cctvcamerapros.com/raspberry-pi/ip-camera-raspberry-pi-youtube-live-video-streaming-server.html and put in cron job, bet that is only to check one cam process. Is there some better idea?

Comment: Please re-read the guidance for the tags you've used.  This is clearly a question about _using_ FFmpeg, not about __programming__, so is off-topic for Stack Overflow.  It _might_ be suitable for [su] or [unix.se]: consult the Help Centre for the site before you post.

Answer (score 1):

Solution to automatically check process status and start ffmpeg if not startet.
Add cron job by: crontab -e
Add row: * * * * * /home/user/start_youtube_stream_cron.sh

```
#start_youtube_stream_cron.sh:
#!/bin/bash


#BEE OUTSIDE CAMx
SERVICE="ffmpeg"
RTSP_URL="rtsp://user:psw@192.168.0.101:554"
YOUTUBE_URL="rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2"
YOUTUBE_KEY="<Youtube secret key 1>"

#BEE INSIDE CAM
RTSP_URL2="rtsp://user:psw@192.168.0.102:554"
YOUTUBE_KEY2="<Youtube secret key 2>"


COMMAND="ffmpeg -f lavfi -i anullsrc -rtsp_transport tcp -i ${RTSP_URL} -tune zerolatency -vcodec libx264 -t 12:00:00 -pix_fmt + -c:v copy -c:a aac -strict experimental -f flv ${YOUTUBE_URL}/${YOUTUBE_KEY} -nostdin -nostats"


COMMAND2="ffmpeg -f lavfi -i anullsrc -rtsp_transport tcp -i ${RTSP_URL2} -tune zerolatency -vcodec libx264 -t 12:00:00 -pix_fmt + -c:v copy -c:a aac -strict experimental -f flv ${YOUTUBE_URL}/${YOUTUBE_KEY2} -nostdin -nostats"


if /usr/bin/pgrep $SERVICE > /dev/null
then
        echo "${SERVICE} is already running."
else
        echo "${SERVICE} is NOT running! Starting now..."
        $COMMAND &
        $COMMAND2 &
fi
```